# INFILE stops data step whenever there are no matching inputs read from external file

Tags: sas

My data step stops when my INFILE command does not return a matching value from external file source. Why is that?

I have work._input dataset with these values:

```
fname
cus_01.txt
cus_02.txt
cus_03.txt
```

Here are the values of each external text files:

cus_01.txt:

```
ID: 0001
Firstname: John
Lastname: White
```

cus_02.txt:

```
This is just a dummy/empty dataset
```

cus_03.txt:

```
ID: 0002
Firstname: Mike
Lastname: Harrel
```

Code:

```
%let sPath = /root/documents/files;

data work._output;

    set work._input;
    length firstname lastname path f2r $512. fname $32.;

    path = symget('sPath');
    f2r = catx("/", path, fname);

    infile a filevar=f2r;

    input @'Firstname:' firstname $;
    input @'Lastname:' lastname $;

    output work._output;

run;
```

OUTPUT:

First iteration of the data step this would be the value:

```
Firstname    Lastname    fname
John         White       cus_01.txt
```

However, in the second iteration of the data step, no matching "Firstname" and "Lastname" will be found in cus_02.txt file and this will cause the data step to stop processing hence, the third iteration for will not occur and cus_03.txt will not be read.

May I know why?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you have 4 input file with cus_01.txt, cus_02.txt and cus_04.txt having data and cus_02.txt empty ?

Comment: Do you mean cus_02.txt really has no values when opened? Haven't tried that and that would not be a case since I'm sure all the external files will have values in it but not all have the Firstname and Lastname string. When processing the cus_02.txt file, no Firstname and Lastname string was found and that's where the problem begins since data step didn't process the next obs which is the cus_03.txt.

Comment: Sorry What happens if you have 4 input file with cus_01.txt, cus_02.txt and cus_04.txt having data and `cus_03.txt` empty ?

Comment: It will process _cus_01.txt_ and _cus_02.txt_ then will stop right there since _cus_03.txt_ doesn't have the matching string `Lastname` and `Firstname`

Comment: Post the ERRORS, WARNINGS or NOTES shown in the Log window

Comment: No ERROR and WARNING just NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT
@'character string' scanned past the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner loop over the input in order to read all lines from the file.  The loop needs a termination condition, the condition will involve a flag variable that is managed automatically and provided by `infile` `end=` option.

(Untested)

```
data work._output;

  set work._input;
  length firstname lastname path f2r $512. fname $32.;

  path = symget('sPath');
  f2r = catx("/", path, fname);

  file_end = 0; * reset just in case;
  infile a filevar=f2r end=file_end;

  do while (not file_end);

    input @'Firstname:' firstname $;
    input @'Lastname:' lastname $;

    output work._output;

  end;
run;
```

Without the inner loop, after each input the filevar advanced to the next filename provided by `set _input`.

Note: This operates differently than `INFILE "<wildcarded filename specification>"` which does not need an inner loop.

Also, you will have a problem when line pairs `Firstname:` and `Lastname:` do not synchronize (such as when one of the two is not present or an additional data line is present (such as `MiddleInitial:`))

Comment: Hi Richard, I encountered syntax error in the not (file_end) expecting one of the following (, =.

Comment: Fixing to `do while (condition)`

Comment: That's my problem, if neither of `Firstname` nor `Lastname` is in the text file, data step wouldn't proceed to next obs in _work._input_

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but doesn't work. Still doesn't proceed after reading obs 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution.

I added inner loop to process all observation of the external file and used name matching instead of @'character-string'

S/O to Tom of SAS Communities for the suggestions!

```
%let sPath = /root/documents/files;

data work._output;

set work._input;
length firstname lastname path f2r $512. fname $32.;

path = symget('sPath');
f2r = catx("/", path, fname);

infile a filevar=f2r dlm=":" end=eof truncover;

do while(not eof);
   input Label $ value $;
   if Label =: 'Firstname' then firstname = value;
   if Label =: 'Lastname' then lastname = value;
end;
```

run;